# How to completely empty input text even when empty by default

Tags: jquery

I have several inputs, some are provided with default value, some are empty, and **filled up by a select value dynamically**.

When I do a select, the value of select box is inserted into the input text.

The problem is when textfield is empty, and then later filled up with the select value, and then using a reset/clear button, the input text is not emptied, yet it is still holding the dynamic inserted value:

Inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="yahoo">
<input type="text" value="some default value" name="google">
<button class="button clear" type="button" accesskey="x">Clear</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('button.clear').click(function () {
  $('input').val(''); // this clears google, but not yahoo
});
```

And some select box input the values dynamically to textfields.
Any idea to completely empty the textfield?
Thanks

Steps:

1. I do change a select box
2. The value of select is inserted into textfield. All is well
3. The problem is when default is empty, the clear button do not empty the textfield (which is dynamically filled up)

I will clarify my question with simplified code:

```
$('select').swicthClass();

$.fn.swicthClass = function (options) {
 // .............
};

var src = 'some-value-from-select-box'; // hence good, bad etc
$('body.bad').find('input[name="yahoo"]').val(src); 



<select>
  <option selected="selected" value="good">Good</option>
      <option value="bad">Bad</option>
      <option value="worse">Worse</option>
      <option value="damn">Damn</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your example (missing a quote around input), is this the problem?

Comment: No, thanks, just typho from simplication. Updated accordingly

Comment: Any error logs in the console?

Comment: @swan works for me http://jsfiddle.net/ZzLts/

Comment: It just can't be, there is something else going on,

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: yahoo is also dynamically filled up with select value (but default to empty). This is the actual problem. When yahoo is filled up, the clear button do not empty the yahoo textfield. Thanks

Comment: @swan it's time for you to post the whole code so we can reproduce the problem... IMHO it being filled in dynamically should have no effect. Maybe if the input itself is created dynamically...

Comment: @gdoron The actual issue is the (empty by default, but later filled up) textfield not emptied totally/ when cleared. Its hard to explain, sorry :( There is arbitrary insertion of values into those empty, or even replacing those with defaults. This arbitrary value is that stubborn to be cleared.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/J7GLX/

Comment: Zoltan Toth, thanks a lot. Could you kindly make it an answer. It will possibly remove/ change my current plugin, since yours is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this

```js
$('button.clear').click(function () {
  $('input').val('');
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
  var src = 'good';
  $('[name=yahoo]').val(src); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" name="yahoo" >
<input type="text" value="some default value" name="google">
<button class="button clear" type="button" accesskey="x">Clear</button>

<select>
  <option selected="selected" value="good">Good</option>
  <option value="bad">Bad</option>
  <option value="worse">Worse</option>
  <option value="damn">Damn</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, must go back to drawing room

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this other way to do it :

```
  $('button.clear').click(function () {
    $('input').attr('value', '') ;// this clears google, but not yahoo
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to the clear button to be exclusive to those with values. It should empty anything with or without value (either default in HTML or dynamically on the fly when I select).